# Convert XML file to JSON

Tags: json, xml, angular

In Angular 8 I have to send an XML contents to the server. 
I prefer converting it to JSON and then it send with:
this.http.post (`${BASE_URL}`,body).subscribe

Is it a wise step ?

Generally: How can I read a file in client side and copy its contents into body ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools and libraries for converting XML to JSON, and they all do it differently. All of them have different strengths and weaknesses; they differ in what kinds of XML they handle well. If the JSON that you want to generate has already been defined by a third party, then you're unlikely to find a tool that generates precisely the desired format. In such cases you're better off writing the conversion rules yourself in XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install "xml2js" dependency.I hope it will helps you.

```
 import { parseString } from "xml2js";

 let xml = `<book><title>Some title</title>
    <description>some description </description>
    <author>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>some author name</name>
    </author>
    <review>nice book</review>
    <review>this book sucks</review>
    <review>amazing work</review></book>
    `;
        parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
          console.dir(result);
        });
      }
```

Comment: Hi Kris, Komal. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

[jsonxml](https://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/) should what you're looking for.

```
function xml2json(xml,  // element or document DOM node
                  tab)  // tab or indent string for pretty output formatting
                        // omit or use empty string "" to supress.
                        // returns JSON string
```